# Calculating packet loss rate in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I am new to Inet/Omnet++ and would like to calculate the packet loss ratio for each link in the wireless network. It is obvious that receiving packets which destination address does not match the node is not considered. I assume I have to use this formula :

Packet Loss Ratio = TotalLostPackets / SentPackets

How to calculate it in omnet++? All approaches are excepted.
Also, I want to calculate

1. the global ratio in the whole network,
2. the average of end-to-end delay time,
3. the global total of throughput,
4. the global total of goodput, and
5. the average and sum of all node energy-consuming.

My ned file is the following:

```
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.contract.IIntegratedVisualizer;

network Net80211
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;
        @display("bgb=650,450;bgi=background/terrain");
    submodules:
        visualizer: <default("IntegratedCanvasVisualizer")> like IIntegratedVisualizer if hasVisualizer() {
            parameters:
                @display("p=640,15;is=s");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                @display("p=640,112;is=s");
        }
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=638,56;is=s");
        }
        host[numHosts]: AdhocHost {
            parameters:
                @display("r=,,#707070;p=300,200;is=s");
        }
        statsModule: StatsModule {

            @display("p=639,169;i=block/cogwheel;is=s");
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some information about the type of wireless network you use? Could you add the NED description of your network? Do you want to calculate packet loss ratio separately for every communication link or a global ratio for the whole network? In which layer do you want to obtain these statistics (data link, network, transport,...)? Usually in wireless systems there is an ARQ mechanism which re-transmits unconfirmed (i.e. lost) frames.

Comment: I want to calculate the global ratio in the whole network, my ned is as next comment

Comment: I suggest editing your question and adding the NED instead of adding an answer.

Comment: Okay dear Jerzy D, I edit my question by adding NED source. Thank you very much